# Distribute self-signed certificate in internal network

Tags: networking, dhcp, certificate

I have an internal CA with a self-signed root certificate. This CA then signs all internal web servers as well as a cert for 802.1X WiFi auth.

Is there any way to distribute this CA's certificate to all clients? Using public CA is pricey and as far as I know, Let's Encrypts handshake only supports publically accessible sites. GPO is applicable for Windows-only environments. This network, however, contains Mac and Linux workstations as well as a large number of phones and a couple of smart TVs.

I was wondering if there is something like a DHCP option which would seamlessly add this self-signed CA's certificate to trusted certificates. I know that such a simple option would impose massive security risks (man-in-the-middle SSL proxy).

When you, however, connect to 802.1X network on Windows the system asks if you trust this certificate. Maybe there is some way of adding temporary cert that would be trusted only for that network's resources.

Comment: You can have your clients install the certificate.  Let’s Encrypt certificates are trusted by all major operating systems and browsers.  Even if you use a certificate signed by a trusted CA, the client, still had to have the certificate installed.

Comment: It would seem unlikely that a generic system like DHCP could help as it would need to be something already trusted so as not to allow third parties to insert their can key - thus "seemless" would seem impossible in the general case - but could be tied in to other setup work (for example Installing OS from image,/or part of a login script or Puppet rule)